# How to define switch cases within regex?

Tags: java, regex

How can I make a single regex that does the following:

"in general, do a generic regex. But if specific characters follow each other, examine the string following these specific characters in a different way"?

```
one == two && three | four
```

The general regex would be: `[&|=\s]+`.

Which would result in when splitting: `one, two, three, four`.

But what if I want to apply a different regex everytime there is a `=`character, and want the expression coming after the `=` to stop only at the `|` character? 
So that I'd get the result: `one, two && three, four`.

How could I do this?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, (at least to me). Are you thinking something like this: `[=one|]|[=two|=three|]|[=four|]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
(?=[&|=\s])[&|\s]*(?:=[^|]*?[|][&|=\s]+)?
```

Or in free-spacing mode with explanation:

```
(?=[&|=\s])  # make sure there is at least a single separator character ahead;
             # this is important, otherwise you would get empty matches, and
             # depending on your implementation split every non-separator
             # character apart.
[&|\s]*      # same as before but leave out =
(?:          # start a (non-capturing) group; it will be optional and treat the
             # special =...| case
  =          # match a literal =
  [^|]*?     # match 0 or more non-| characters (as few as possible)
  [|]        # match a literal | ... this is the same as \|, but this is more
             # readable IMHO
  [&|=\s]+   # and all following separator characters
)?           # make the whole thing optional
```

[Try it out.](http://fiddle.re/5bxh6)

**EDIT:**

I just realised, this swallows up the central part, but you want to return that as well. In that case, you might be better off with matching instead of splitting (using `find`). This pattern should do the trick:

```
=[&|=\s]*([^|]+?)[&|=\s]*[|]|([^&|=\s]+)
```

Now either the first or second capturing group will contain the desired result. Here is an explanation:

```
#this consists of two alternatives, the first one is the special case
  =            # match a literal =
  [&|=\s]*     # consume more separator characters
  ([^|]+?)     # match 1 or more non-| characters (as few as possible) and
               # capture (group 1)
  [&|=\s]*     # consume more separator characters
  [|]          # match a literal |
|              # OR
  ([^&|=\s]+)  # match 1 or more non-separator characters (as many as possible)
               # and capture (group 2)
```

[Try it out.](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDgsSBlJlY2lwZRjr6lwM/index.html)